# Раскрасить текст разными цветами

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется 4 цвета: red, yellow, blue, green

Имеется динамичный текст длина которого постоянно меняется.

Вопрос: Как раскрасить 100% текста 25% каждого цвета?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: silver;
  font-size: 2em;
}

span {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 25%, yellow 25%, yellow 50%, blue 50%, blue 75%, green 75%);
  color: white;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<span>Текст произвольной длины</span>
```

Comment: Хм. Мне казалось по формулировке, что ТС хотел раскрасить именно текст ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, так я ж текст и раскрасил?

Comment: Столкнулась с проблемой в сафари для `-webkit-background-clip: text;`, появляются артефакты вокруг элемента, никак починить не могу..

Comment: @kizoso, у меня нет сафари. Попробуй со сглаживанием шрифта поиграться.

Answer (score 2):

Когда-то я делал на JS разноцветный анимированный медленно переливающийся текст, но тогда моих знаний языка было меньше, и сейчас написал бы по-другому. Но может пригодиться:

```js
var mytext = "Когда-то я делал на JS разноцветный анимированный медленно переливающийся текст, но тогда моих знаний языка было меньше, и сейчас написал бы по-другому. Но может пригодится. Скрипт рассчитан на разукраску статического текста, но это поправимо.";
var fontface = ["Arial", "Lucida Console", "Comic Sans Ms", "MS Sans Serif", "Arial Black", "verdana", "courier"],
st = 0,
out = document.getElementById("out"),
e = "";
for(i = 0; i < mytext.length; i ++)e += "<span id=p" + i + ">" + mytext[i] + "</span>";
out.innerHTML = e;
var st = sti = stb = 0, it = it1 = bt = bt1 = "";
for(i = 0; i < mytext.length; i++){
 var b2 = document.getElementById("p" + i);
 if(sti == 8){sti = 0; it = "<i>"; it1= "</i>"}else{it = it1 = ""};
 if(stb == 10){stb = 0; bt = "<b>"; bt1 = "</b>"}else{bt = bt1 = ""};
 b2.innerHTML = "<font face='" + fontface[st] + "'>" + it + bt + b2.innerHTML + bt1 + it1 + "</font>";
 st ++; sti ++; stb ++;
 if(st == fontface.length)st = 0;
}
function decorate(){
 for(i = 0; i < mytext.length; i ++){ 
  var b1 = document.getElementById("p" + i),
  R = 176 + Math.floor(80 * Math.sin(i + st / 17)),
  G = 176 + Math.floor(80 * Math.sin(i / 2.7 + st / 10)),
  B = 176 + Math.floor(80 * Math.sin(i / 4.3 - st / 7));
  b1.style.color = "rgb(" + R + ", " + G + ", " + B + ")";
 }
 st++;
}
decorate();
setInterval("decorate()", 100); // если эту строку убрать, отключится анимация
```

```html
<body bgcolor=#003>
<div id=out></div>
</body>
```

Скрипт рассчитан на разукраску статического текста, но это поправимо.

Comment: Ля, наркомания :D